# Boton en Activity NavigationView se muestra en todos mis fragment

Tags: java, android

Qué puede ser? No tiene mayor código ese botón. Es un botón simple.[image: Esta es la InicioActivity que es un NavigationView[![La imagen 1 es el InicioActivity que es un NavigationView y la imagen 2 y 3 son fragment de esta activity]

[image: Fragment1]

[image: Fragment2]

LAYOUT (El boton CONTINUAR de la imagen es el "btnseleccionar" en el Layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/new_login_gradients"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="18dp"
    android:paddingRight="18dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/contenedor"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.matias.finalcode.InicioActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_inicio">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_white_24dp"
        android:text="Bienvenido/a "
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtnombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="nombre"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="¿En qué ciudad sacarás Número?"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"></Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sp1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="¿A cuál servicio deseas ir?"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"></Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sp2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="¿Cuál de ellos elegiras?"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"></Spinner>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"></Spinner>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"></Spinner>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnseleccionar"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sp3"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_signup"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Continuar"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: muestra el layout (xml)

Comment: Amigo es importante siempre agregar el código o el layout como comenta armen! en realidad el problema es sencillo de solucionar pero si agregas el layout sería de mucha ayuda a otros desarrolladores! :) saludos! @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas

Comment: @armen arriba subí el layout. El boton CONTINUAR de la imagen es el "btnseleccionar" en el Layout. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Gracias @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas pero cual es el layout donde cargas tus Fragments, los cargas en un Framelayout me imagino? Como estas agregando los Fragments y en que layout?

Comment: tu layout contenedor debe incluir solo el FrameLayout. Los views (TextView, EditText, Buttons ...) deben de ir en los layout de los fragments

Comment: @armen lo qué pasa es que en el contenedor es donde puse el botón y otros textview, porque si los pongo en los fragment el contenedor queda vacío y muestra la pantalla en blanco.